# Proof of: if relation R has attribute(reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity...) then relation R^2 has the same attribute.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I prove that if any relation R has for example symmetry, relation R^2 has also symmetry?
For reflexivity and ireflexivity I have a counterexample, but I dont know how to make a general prove for symmetry and transitivity.
And I am also interested in going through some prove and come to the point when I realise it has a counterexample.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying. What is your idea? What do you have problems with?